# Where should I add the interstitial ad?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ads, banner, interstitial

I managed to test a simple app and the ads (banner and interstitial) work as expected (the test ones, because the real ones don't, idk why).
The problem is I want to integrate the ads into my main application. I did it for the banner and it works but don't know how to handle the interstitial. For the test app, I called a function when a button was pressed, but here in my app I don't want a button to be pressed in order to show an interstitial, I want this to happen every time the player dies. And I don't know how to do this.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class ads : MonoBehaviour
{
    private BannerView bannerView;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private void RequestBanner()...
    private void RequestInterstitial()
    {
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
        this.interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        this.interstitial.LoadAd(request);
    }
    public void GameOverSoShowInterstitial()
    {
        if (this.interstitial.IsLoaded())
        {
            this.interstitial.Show();
        }
    }
    void Start()
    {
        MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });
        this.RequestBanner();
        this.RequestInterstitial();
    }
}
```

^this is my ads script
but it is located in the [second scene named Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2T1g.png), but since the interstitial should appear when the player dies, I should move that GameObject in the [other scene that is the actual game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af25G.png), because it's impossible to die in the 'menu' section. And also, for checking when the ad has to appear I should use the GameManager, right? which is in the game scene, too.

```
public void GameOver()
    {
        gameOver = true;
        gameScore = score.GetComponent<Score>().getScore();
        score.SetActive(false);
        Invoke("ActivateGameOverCanvas", 1);
        pauseBtn.SetActive(false);
    }
```

^this is the part with the gameover from gamemanager, so I think here I should introduce somehow an instruction that would generate the interstitial ad, but I don't have a clue. I tried to add the 'ads' script to gamemanager too, so at the end of the execution of GameOver function from gamemanager to call the GameOverSoShowInterstitial from ads, but it didn't work.

Any ideas? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Using objects from another Scene**

When it comes to using scripts/objects from once Scene to another we generally put that object into a `MonoBehaviour` built-in method `DontDestroyOnLoad(object);`. By Using this method we can make sure that `object` will not be destroyed when you change the scenes. Assuming that Menu your script is in Menu Scene you can Put that object in DontDestroyOnLoad() method and it will not get destroyed throughout the game.

**2. Using the Method from Add script**

For this we have multiple options. Like you can find the Object Using `GameObject.FindObjectOfType()` or `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag()`, etc. But using Gameobject.FindXXX() method can be heavy on performance side. The battre way is to use singleton pattern. In this you basically create an object when your Game Starts(When you need the object). And there will be no other object of the same type *(it mean that there will be no other object with the same script attached to the object)*.

**3. See both of the points in Action**
**Your Ad script**
you don't have to change any thing just have to add the Singleton pattern.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class ads : MonoBehaviour
{
    //This is a static instance of this class so that you can access it from anywhere from you game, Without creating any creating a new Object.(Point #2)
    public static ads instance {
    get;         //These are the getter and setter methods of native C# find the reference below
    private set;
    }

    private Awake()
    {
        //Check if the instance is already assigned(if there is already an object with this same script attached)
        if(instance == null)
        {
           instance = this; //If instance is empty the assign this object to the instance
           DoNotDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject); //This line will stop Unity from destroying the object when you load new scene.(Point #1)
        }
        else
        {
           Destroy(this.gameObject); //since there is already an object of with script destroy this object so that there will be no conflicts between multiple instances of the same class.
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });
        this.RequestBanner();
        this.RequestInterstitial();
    }
    public void ShowInterstitialAd()
    {
        ... Show your Ad
    }
}
```

**Game Manager Script**

```
public void PlayerDie() //assuming that you have a method for when your Player dies
{
    ...
    ads.instance.ShowInterstitialAd(); //Call the ShowInterstitialAd() method because the object will not be destroyed when you load another scene.
}
```

I'm basically done here. I hope this helps you. here are some of the reference that might be helpful to understand this further.

[Singleton pattern](https://youtu.be/hQE8lQk9ikE?t=89)

[Getter and setter methods of native C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties)

Comment: public static ads instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("gameovertag");
            }

            return instance;
        }
        set
        {
            
        }

    }

Comment: i did what you said and this was the way I found the getter should be written (i added the tag gameovertag to the object with the gameover canvas), but what about the setter?

Comment: you are not suppose to do in Get or set methods, I've also send you a reference video to understand the Singleton pattern.  Please Watch the video and because He'll be able to explain you batter then me.

Comment: And the reason for using get; and set; methods. is that we can set ```get;``` method as public while ```set;``` method can be privet, so that no matter what we can't change the instance from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're a lord. I've managed to show the banner and also the interstitial, but even if the banner is continuously showing, the interstitial test ad appears only once, when I die the first time. Am I missing something or this is the way it should work?

Comment: in fact, the console log keeps telling me that an interstitial ad is generated every time I die, but when testing it, my phone returns me only a single ad

Comment: I think you should read the official documentation to understand how to display the Interstitial ad, because you have to request the ad every-time you hide the ad. Please read [Interstitial Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/interstitial)